# WinForms - Borderless DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms, borderless

I have a stock winform datetimepicker that looks something like this...
[image: winform datetimepicker]

I would like to make it look something like this...

[image: winform datetimepicker modified]

The `WinForm` `TextBox` has a borderless option and I manually created a horizontal rule to give the illusion of a seamless underlined `TextBox` but the `DateTimePicker` doesn't seem to have a borderless option.

Is there something I can do to either make the `DateTimePicker` look like the example above or at least remove the borders so I can manually place the underline?

Comment: You could subclass the `DateTimePicker`, override `OnPaint`, call `base.OnPaint` from within your overridden method, and then paint white over the black pixels you want to be white.

Comment: What you have to do is create a custom WInForm extending the behaviour of the DateTimePicker. This is the cleanest solution and here is a tutorial for that: http://devblog.antongochev.net/2008/07/07/create-custom-ui-appearance-for-winforms-controls-part-1/

Comment: @Niko I don't think DTP allows appearance customization (it's a wrapper around Windows common control which does all painting etc.)

Comment: You can "clip" the borders by putting DTP inside a container control (panel or user control) and setting DTP.Left = DPT.Top = -1, Container.Height = DTP.Height - 1, Container.Width = DTP.Width - 2

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for seeding the idea for the solution! I ended up placing the dateTimePicker (DTP) in a panel and then just adjusting the size of the panel to "clip out" the edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer with the least amount of code would be to place a panel, place the control in the panel and then "clip" the border of the dateTimePicker (DTP) by reducing the size of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the custom look for the control, you have to override the WndProc method, which is the method that processes all the window messages for this control.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
IntPtr hDC = GetWindowDC(m.HWnd);
Graphics gdc = Graphics.FromHdc(hDC);
switch (m.Msg)
{
case WM_NC_PAINT:
 SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_ERASEBKGND, hDC, 0);
 SendPrintClientMsg();
 SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_PAINT, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
 OverrideControlBorder(gdc);

 m.Result = (IntPtr)1; // indicate msg has been processed
 break;
case WM_PAINT: base.WndProc(ref m);
 OverrideControlBorder(gdc);
 OverrideDropDown(gdc);
 break;
  case  WM_NC_HITTEST:
 base.WndProc(ref m);
 if (DroppedDown)
  this.Invalidate(this.ClientRectangle, false);
 break;
default:
 base.WndProc(ref m);
 break;
}
ReleaseDC(m.HWnd, hDC);
gdc.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as I can get it:

You will have to make an image for the drop down button.

[image]

```
public class SexyDateTimePicker : DateTimePicker
{
    public SexyDateTimePicker() : base()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, this.ClientSize.Height -1, this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height -1);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.DateOrTimePicker_675, new Point(this.ClientRectangle.X + this.ClientRectangle.Width - 16, this.ClientRectangle.Y));
    }

}
```